# Interpolating target path in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark 3.5 to process some requests, which come bucketed into month and date:

```
/09/27/json-lines-file-with-a-long-name
```

I'm doing some filtration and want the results to end up bucketed in the very same way (processed requests for Sept 27 go into `09/27` directory). I have created `hour` and `day` columns, so the question is whether it's technically possible to recreate the same directory bucketing by interpolating path in some way? Here's an example of how it may looked like:

```scala
// obviously this doesn't work
df
  .write
  .options(...)
  .json("$month/$day")
```

I'm aware that this will likely bring performance penalty and require special partitioning (that will create uneven partitions in my case). I've seen some examples with `partitionBy`, which are almost what i'm looking for, but i believe that functionality is not available or was renamed in Spark 3. I also understand that i can do it in a simple for-loop, but curious about existence of a "right" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of spark 3.5, `partitionBy` still exists and it is almost perfect for what you want to do (See the doc of [DataFrameWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html)).

It will write your files as follows:

```
/month=09/day=27/json-lines-file-with-a-long-name
```

I don't know of any way to get rid of the `column_name=` part simply by configuring `partitionBy`. A solution would be to rename the files afterwards. This solution avoids reading each part of the dataframe separately which would most likely be much slower.

```scala
// An example
spark.range(5)
     .select('id % 2 as "m", 'id % 4 as "m2",  'id)
     .write.mode("overwrite")
     .partitionBy("m", "m2")
     .json("test2")
```

```bash
> tree test2
tree test2
test2
├── m=0
│   ├── m2=0
│   │   ├── part-00003-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
│   │   └── part-00015-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
│   └── m2=2
│       └── part-00009-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
├── m=1
│   ├── m2=1
│   │   └── part-00006-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
│   └── m2=3
│       └── part-00012-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
└── _SUCCESS
```

Then, if the names are not good enough, you can rename the files. Here is an example for the local file system but a similar approach would work as well for S3 or HDFS.

```scala
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path, Paths}

def rename_spark_partitions(path : Path) {
    if (Files.isDirectory(path))
        Files.list(path).forEach(rename_spark_partitions _)
    val name = path.getFileName.toString
    if(name.contains("="))
        Files.move(path, path.resolveSibling( name.split("=")(1))) 
}
rename_spark_partitions(Paths.get("test2"))
```

```
> tree test2
test2
├── 0
│   ├── 0
│   │   ├── part-00003-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
│   │   └── part-00015-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
│   └── 2
│       └── part-00009-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
├── 1
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── part-00006-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
│   └── 3
│       └── part-00012-8d4921cb-1280-416a-8a0c-cc133b15c42d.c000.json
└── _SUCCESS
```